# java timestamp with timezone to store in ORACLE DB

Tags: oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to insert `Timestamp` with `Timezone` in Oracle DB using java JDBC. I have a timestamp in one variable and need to append Timezone, like Europe/Paris, to my timestamp and store it in the DB which has a column of datatype Timestamp with Timezone.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? One of the first sites I have found seems to have a proper solution to this problem, check: [How to handle time zone in Java](http://palashray.com/2010/11/02/how-to-handle-oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-from-java/)

Comment: In That site it has been explained how to convert time from one zone to other. Basically in my case date and time will remain same but only timezone needs to be appended with that date and time and to store in Oracle DB

Comment: Can you then provide a sample code and expected result?

Comment: I have time stamp as 2013-10-01 09:50:00. Now need to append 'Europe/Paris' as timezone to above time stamp and then to store in DB column having data type as Time stamp with Timezone. So the expected Output should be :- '2013-10-01 09:50:00 Europe/Paris'